# MVC Validation not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a view that has a textbox to enter a user name and then two checkboxes.  It will be use to add said user name to the roles marked by the checkboxes.  The text box should not allow empty/null strings to be entered and if the user name already exists, warn the person.

View

```
@model QIEducationWebApp.Models.UserAdmin

<h1 class="page-header">Add New User</h1>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                User Name:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="table-row">
                Role:
            </th>
            <td class="table-row">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UserRole,
                    @ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, " -- Select Role -- ", new { @class="form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserRole)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td class="table-row-blank"></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table-row-button">
                <input class="button" type="submit" value="Create" />
                <input type="button" class="button" value="Cancel" 
                    onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("AllUsers")'" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Model

```
[EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
[Remote("ExistUser", "Admin", HttpMethod = "POST",
    ErrorMessage = "User is assinged, Edit instead")]
[DataMemberAttribute()]
public global::System.String UserName
{
    get
    {
        return _UserName;
    }
    set
    {
        OnUserNameChanging(value);
        ReportPropertyChanging("UserName");
        _UserName = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
        ReportPropertyChanged("UserName");
        OnUserNameChanged();
    }
}
private global::System.String _UserName;
partial void OnUserNameChanging(global::System.String value);
partial void OnUserNameChanged();
```

Controller validation method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult ExistUser(String UserName)
{
    bool exist = db.UserAdmins.Any(u => u.UserName == UserName);

    return Json(!exist);
}
```

Controller post method

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Director")]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddNewUser(UserAdmin user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.UserAdmins.AddObject(user);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("AllUsers");
    }
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(db.UserRoles, "UserRoleID", "UserRole1", user.UserRole);
    return View(user);
}
```

Currently it allows empty strings to be passed in on submit instead of showing the error.  And my custom validation isn't even firing off and my debug is getting hit.

I have used this in other parts of the application and those still work.

P.S. If you guys need more code, just let me know and I'll get it up.

EDIT:: Completely different code than the original post.

Volkan Paksoy pointed out my missing ModelState.IsValid and view return.

And for the client side validation i was missing my

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: use [Required] attribute

Comment: Modify your POST Action to take in an instance of the model, as opposed to just the string value.

Comment: @HadiHassan That is already in there, didn't matter

Comment: @ChrisBohatka If you mean to just pass in User user and then in the code switch UserName to User.UserName, that didn't work

Comment: If client side validation is not working its because either you have not included the relevant scripts in the correct order (have you included `jquery{version}.js` prior to the 2 scripts you have shown?) or its not enabled. And you have not shown your POST method (only the method for Remote validation) so can't tell if you may have errors there.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Added the post method.  I have the scripts at the top and in the same order as used with other validations.

Comment: I still don't see `jquery{version}.js` anywhere - that must come before the other 2 scripts. Check the html your generating to make sure its included and is in the correct order. Note also you should consider adding `public bool IsAdmin { get; set; }` and public bool IsDirector { get; set; }` to your view model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as @Chris Bohatka suggested, you have to use your model as the parameter (User class in this case)

Then you have to check the status of the ModelState like this:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    // There is an error on the page, load the same view to display the errors
}

// Model is fine, carry on with the other stuff...
```

I debugged and saw the "Must enter a User Name" in ModelState errors collection so what you have to do is return to the same view so that user can see the error and fix it.

Comment: Thank you.  That's one part down.  I didn't know that it just reloaded the page with the error.

Comment: Its displaying the error for when the box is empty.  The client side validation on whether or not the user is in the system already is not getting hit.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you do not have client side validation enabled, in which case it will do the post even if the fields are not correct.  Also, in your post controller method you aren't checking validity of ModelState, which may be invalid, meaning there's a validation issue you aren't trapping for.  Add this to your controller method:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid) { do work };
```

And make sure you have these lines in web.config to enable client side (JavaScript) validation, in which case the post won't happen until the field values are valid:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```